# Sublime Text 3 - Is there support for inline CSS intellisense

Tags: sublimetext3, code-completion

I'm coming from VS IDE and like ST3 a lot but still learning all the features.  When I start entering inline CSS via the style attribute, VS will drop down options that match what I've typed.  (i.e. if I enter "wi" I can see option for "windows", "width", etc).

Can ST3 do the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Hayaku - tools for writing CSS faster](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Hayaku%20-%20tools%20for%20writing%20CSS%20faster) might do what you ask for.

> Fuzzy abbreviations, support for preprocessors (Sass, Less, Stylus)
>   and a lot of other features in easily configurable set of tools for
>   writing CSS faster

There are a bunch of packages out there for Sublime Text, if the Hayaku package does not do what you want, you might want to [browse through the available packages at Will Bond's Package Control website](https://sublime.wbond.net/browse).